# Executing a function when a delay of 1 second is activated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to run 2 animations. But I need the second to start a second after the first using some type of delay. For example:

http://jsfiddle.net/4p2beak4/

```
(div).delay(function(){
 alert(2000 seconds)
 excecute the second animation
 return 2000;
}).animate..

    $("#coolDiv").css({
      left: $('#container').width() - ($('#coolDiv').width() + $('#coolDiv2').width())
    }).delay(2000).animate({"left":"0px"}, 9000, function() {

       $("#coolDiv2").css({
      left: $('#container').width() - ($('#coolDiv').width() + $('#coolDiv2').width())
    }).animate({"left":"0px"}, 9000);
    });
```

I am trying to show the first text, and after a second show another without being put on top.

http://jsfiddle.net/7vf9w3Lx/

I need achieve this effect

https://codepen.io/aamirafridi/pen/qgutw

One sentence followed by another

Comment: "I dont want use a timeout.." Why not? This is literally what a timeout is for.

Comment: @MikeC I am trying to show the first text, and after a second show another without being put on top.

http://jsfiddle.net/7vf9w3Lx/

Comment: I need achieve this effect https://codepen.io/aamirafridi/pen/qgutw

Comment: I need achieve this effect 

https://codepen.io/aamirafridi/pen/qgutw  

One sentence followed by another. Okay, it does not matter if we use timeout

Comment: like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/4p2beak4/1/

Comment: @adeneo Thank you! But see that the second animation overlaps the first.
I want anything as this https://codepen.io/aamirafridi/pen/qgutw

Comment: Of course it does, there's easing, and then they both end up in the same place. Are you sure you don't just want to put both elements inside another element, and then animate the parent instead

Comment: You know, since you already have an example of how to do that effect, you could just learn how the other person did it by reading their code. [Here's the repo for that plugin.](https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee)

Comment: @MikeC I tried to use it. But it does not work to my need. I want to put several sentences in the same line, without appearing the space of when it is finished. I have my reasons for wanting to create the code for myself.